# Looking for proven libraries for Blackberry or J2ME (HttpConnection)

Tags: blackberry, java-me, httpconnection

I have an application that makes many subsequent calls to a REST service for batching data to a database on the BlackBerry devices. I have tried several methods of using HttpConnection with various streams to see which might perform the best. So far to the same service other Platforms like Windows Mobile and iPhone can handle the downloads at a very minimal time < 1 minute whereas the BlackBerry will take around 6 minutes for the same data.

So my real question is, does anyone know of any proven libraries for J2ME or BlackBerry that will help gain performance while making Http request.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this library [here](http://dftr.ca/?p=273) and see whether it has any improvements you could incorporate